# How can I style a nested tag with a CSS file?

Tags: html, css, nested, tags

I have part of HTML like this and I want to define in separate static CSS file a specific color for the font of the element `a` nested in `h2`.

```css
h1 > a, h2 > a 
{
    color: #c25100;
    font-family: 'Lobster';
}

body {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2>
        <a href="">abc</a>
    </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your way you could change of the color of all anchor tags which is child of h2 elements. To avoid this I would give a class to h2 and then point anchor tag like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
<h2 class="header">
<a href = ''>abc</a></h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header > a {
 color: #c25100;
 font-family: 'Lobster';
}
```